# Same origin policy causes Ajax requests to example.com from www.example.com to be denied?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, same-origin-policy

If you visit a website at http://www.example.com/dir , then any ajax requests to http://example.com/dir/something.php (with the www missing) cause the following message to show up in google chrome's console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/dir/something.php.
Origin http://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What's up with this, and what can be done to fix this?

Edit: It seems that any cookies set by example.com also disappear when you visit www.example.com ?

Comment: The policy insists that the scheme, host name, and port number (as specified) be **exactly** the same.

Comment: @Pointy How do I fix this, then?

Comment: You can fix it by putting all the pages in the same domain.

Comment: They are pointed to the same domain, but if someone manually typed a www in front of the url, it would cause the ajax requests to not work. Is there a way to redirect everything from www to without the www using .htaccess, and will that fix this?

Comment: No, you can't do it on the server side because it's the **browser** that's enforcing the rule.  Why would you allow user input to be used as the URL on an XHR anyway?  You could use JavaScript to make sure any such URLs have the right domain, I guess.

Comment: The base url is supplied to javascript and is pointed at http://example.com. Therefore if the user visits www.example.com, all ajax requests would still be made to http://example.com

Comment: Well do a redirect then initially to make sure the pages served up are in the right domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are different domains and they can serve different content. `www.stackoverflow.com` only redirects to `stackoverflow.com` but technically it can display a site full of ponies instead.

See [*Origin determination rules*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) - it actually uses the exact same `example.com` (*nomen est omen!*) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Subdomains are considered "different domains" thus will be blocked. Included in this is the `www` since it's considered a subdomain of the `example.com`

One can work around this issue by iframe communication since iframes can communicate with the main page content as long as they live in the same top domain.

Comment: What's the subdomain here? Its the same domain except one has www and one doesn't.

Comment: @ClickUpvote the `www` is considered a subdomain. that causes the error.

Comment: If IFrames aren't an option, what's the solution in that case? Can I do redirects via .htaccess?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer if the page tries a request with a different domain, the browser will disallow it - you can't work around that problem with a server-side redirect.

Comment: @Pointy i think I misunderstood that. I think i meant redirect the page so the target domain will match the domain of the page. so visiting the `www` version will redirect to the no-www version, and from there, AJAX will use the no-www urls.

Comment: Yes I think I get it - the redirect needs to happen at the beginning so that the pages are always in the right domain.